# Quickly get the full path+name of the file being edited

Tags: buffers

When editing a a files in a deeply nested folder structure,

how can I quickly copy/yank the full name of the file (including folder path(s) )

Comment: You can try to bind a key to `(kill-new buffer-file-name)`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Please consider posting that as an answer. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

For Helm users, use <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd> (`helm-find-files`) then <kbd>C-u C-c C-k</kbd> (`helm-kill-selection-and-quit`).